# Serial Port no Answer

Tags: c#

i have a phg ADMITTO100 RFID Reader to read Legic and i try to send some CMD´s to this one but it doesn´t answer.

I follow this example [Serial Port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

what have I forgotten? Do I have something to install before using a COM-Port?

The CMD is not right because of the LRC byte but shouldn´t the reader say "no, that was wrong"?

Here my code:

```
        var serialPort = new SerialPort
        {
            PortName = "COM1",
            BaudRate = 9600,
            DataBits = 8,
            Parity = Parity.None,
            StopBits = StopBits.One,
            Handshake = Handshake.None,

            ReadTimeout = 500,
            WriteTimeout = 500,
        };

        serialPort.Open();

        serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) => 
        {
            var message = ((SerialPort)s).ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        });

        serialPort.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler((s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.EventType);
        });

        var buffer = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x36, 0x00 };
        serialPort.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: try this question maybe it helps i had similar problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539869/serial-port-read-c-sharp-console

Comment: Do you use a proper Serial port or a USB <-> Serial port? I have had a lot of problems with the drivers for the USB ones to work properly.. usually solved by trying a different brand

Comment: have you treied to change the timeout to A beeger value? and try to use the ReadLine and WriteLine functions to handle the communication

Comment: It may not say anything The point of an LRC is to know that the packet is complete, if it is wrong you have no way of knowing which part was wrong, it could just be random noise on the comms line (electrical noise does happen). I would suggest sending a properly formed command, the LRC is simple to work out by hand.

Comment: The other thing you could do is actually write a proper command builder (you are going to need it) and use that to send something - I just checked, the RFID tag reader I interfaced used a different protocol altogether. You may find it helpful to handle all comms directly because .NET serial can be rather fragile.

Comment: The Problem was: the device is not set to COM1, sorry